# Unable to Retrieve classic azure Vm's using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a subscription which have a mixed of classic VM's and RM VM's . how ever I'am writing a powershell script which will stop all the VM's in the Subscription. I am unable to retrieve the classic VM's with Get-azurermVM cmdlet. How to get the list of Classic VM's in a subscription? . I have tried below commands and an error was thrown

Add-AzureAccount

PS C:\windows\system32> Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "xxxxx"
Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name xxxxxx doesn't exist.
Parameter name: name
At line:1 char:1
+ Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "xxxxx"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SelectAzureSubscriptionCommand

Comment: welp, subscription doesnt exist, try get-azuresubsction after successfully logging it.

Comment: I have tried that after successful log in, but nothing fruitful

Get-AzureSubscription : The subscription id xxxxxxxxxxx doesn't exist.
Parameter name: id
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId xxxxxxx
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureSubscription], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.GetAzureSubscriptionCommand

Comment: are you sure you have rights in classic Azure API?

Comment: Yes , I can see the list of machines through Portal

Comment: Just because you can see the machines in the Portal does not mean that you have rights to the classic Azure API. You must be an owner/co-owner in order to access the classic Azure API. If you are able to login using `Add-AzureAccount` (not add-Azure*Rm*Account!) you can run `Get-AzureSubscription` without any parameters to list your available subscriptions. If you do not see the desired subscription you are most likely not an owner/co-owner.

Comment: You should use `Get-AzureVM` to get classic VM.